# Upgrading WordPress Core Manually

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to upgrade my WP core files.

Here are the steps I am trying to do:

1. Download the latest version of WP
2. Copy wp-admin, wp-includes folder and the rest of the file except for the wp-content folder and wp-config file.
3. Overwrite this files to the main existing website directory
   Would this work? Are there any issues on this one?

Please help!

Comment: You should consider asking your question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Before you overwrite any files I suggest you to

- Make dump of your MySQL table
- Make a backup for your wordpress directory and files
- (Optional) Check if any of your installed plugins/ addons has any critical issues with the version of WP you are upgrading to.

That being said, yes you are good to go with overwriting the files, keeping in mind your step 2.

Post back if you run into any errors!